# Need Help Using Console.Log() With Awesomium / Awesomium Inspector

Tags: javascript, awesomium

I'm a JS developer working on an Angular Awesomium project - does anyone have a definitive answer on how to enable `console.log()` with the Awesomium Inspector, this is a must for me. I've searched SO, the Awesomium forum and the web, but all answers are just half-baked. Any help would be appreciated.

Right now I'm running 1.7.4.2. I know I can handle `ConsoleMessage` but I don't know where that is, or how to go about using `ConsoleMessage` properly. I would love a pointer to any documentation or a step-by-step walk through on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ConsoleMessage event like this:

```
BaseWebControl.ConsoleMessage += delegate(object sender, ConsoleMessageEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("console.log: " + e.Message);
};
```

btw. You should switch to Awesomium 1.7.5.1